# How to make a related object required?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using MVC 5 with EntityFramework, and I can't seem to make the selection of a related object a required field using Data Annotations.

My model is quite simple.  Here is my Movement.cs model:

```
public class Movement
{
    [Key]
    public int MovementID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Type is required.")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Type cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Persons name is required.")]
    public virtual Person Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Location is required.")]
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }

}
```

The Movement has 2 related entities, Person and Location which are pretty simple mobels.  In my Create Movement Form I use the following ViewModel:

```
public class MovementFormViewModel
{
    public Movement Movement { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Types { get; set; }

    public int? SelectedLocation { get; set; }
    public int? SelectedPerson { get; set; }

}
```

And here's my controller:

```
   private MovementFormViewModel createViewModel(Movement movement)
   {
       var types = new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem{ Text="Transfer", Value = "Transfer" },
                new SelectListItem{ Text="Promotion", Value = "Promotion" },
                new SelectListItem{ Text="N/A", Value = "N/A" }
            };

        var locations = db.Locations.ToArray().Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.LocationID.ToString(),
            Text = x.Name
        });

        var people = db.People.ToArray().Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.PersonID.ToString(),
            Text = x.FullName
        });

        MovementFormViewModel viewModel = new MovementFormViewModel
        {
            Movement = movement,
            Types = types,
            Locations = locations,
            People = people

        };

        return viewModel;

    }


    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View(createViewModel(new Movement()));
    }
```

Finally my create view has the following for my related entities:

```
            @Html.DropDownListFor(
                x => x.SelectedPerson,
                Model.People,
                "-- Select a Person --")

            <p class="text-error">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MarketMovement.Name)
            </p>
```

If I submit the form then I get the validation error that my Person and Location fields are required... but when I select an entry from the drop down list and try to resubmit, the form still raises a validation that the entries are required and I can't proceed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it is not recommend to set DataAnnotations on non-primitive types like here:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Persons name is required.")]
public virtual Person Name { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Location is required.")]
public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
```

What is more in fact your Name property is not a Name but the whole Person object.

Generally the major problem lies in the fact that when you select an item it is not bound to your `MovementFormViewModel.Movement.Person` but it simply sets the `MovementFormViewModel.SelectedPerson`. So  `MovementFormViewModel.Movement.Person` remains empty and the validation error occurs.

I would therefore recommend to remove the Required attribute from the Movement class, because it anyway does not seem to be used. You should move the validation to your view model class instead:

```
public class MovementFormViewModel
{
    public Movement Movement { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Types { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Location is required.")]
    public int SelectedLocation { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Persons name is required.")]
    public int SelectedPerson { get; set; }

}
```

As presented above you cannot use `Nullable<int>` (`int?`), you should use non-nullable ints (`int`) to get the validation work appropriately.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, thank you.  But f I instead move the [Required] tag to the SelectedPerson and SelectedLocation properties in the ViewModel then the validation doesn't trigger

Comment: Ah, changing nullable<int> to <int> was the other part that fixed it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is the Selectedperson actually set in your model when you submit?
For the same task I have created SelectedPersonID and marked it as required.

As described here http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: Yes, it works normally if I remove the [Required] tag.  If I instead move the [Required] tag to the SelectedPerson and SelectedLocation properties in the ViewModel then the validation doesn't trigger